# Sending data from fragment A to fragment B using ViewModel (Android Studio, Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel

My use case is very simple. I have two fragments which need to communicate using ViewModel:

LoginFragment has a an editable email address field, whose value needs to be received in another fragment, called ProfileFragment. A straightforward transmission of a string field. My idea is to input the email address from LoginFragment, update a shared ViewModel, and then receive the email address in ProfileFragment.

**LoginFramgnet XML:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".LoginFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:backgroundTint="#FF9393"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#FFFDD2B5"
            android:text="@string/login"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.37" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**LoginFragment.kt**

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var viewModel: LoginFragmentViewModel


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoginFragmentViewModel::class.java)

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText( activity,"${editTextTextEmailAddress.text} is logged in!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                viewModel.setEmailAddress("${editTextTextEmailAddress.text}")

                Log.i("Info", "${viewModel.emailAddress.value}")

                view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_profileFragment)
    }
```

**ViewModel.kt:**

```
class LoginFragmentViewModel : ViewModel() {


val emailAddress = MutableLiveData<Any>()

fun setEmailAddress(email:String){
    emailAddress.value = email
}
```

}

**ProfileFragment XML:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ProfileFragment">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ProfileFragment.kt:**

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {


private lateinit var viewModel: LoginFragmentViewModel

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoginFragmentViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.emailAddress.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, object : Observer<Any>{
        override fun onChanged(t: Any?) {
            txtEmailAddress.text = t!!.toString()
        }
    })
    Log.i("Info", "${viewModel.emailAddress.value}")
}
```

The Log on LoginFragment registers that the emailAddress in the ViewModel is changed, based on what is input in the editTextTextEmailAddress.

The Log on ProfileFragment returns "null".

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will be provided a different Instance of `LoginFragmentViewModel` - look at the provider in each `Fragment` - `ViewModelProvider(this)...`  meaning `this`, the fragment is the provider and scope.  Use something like : `viewModel by activityViewModels<LoginFragmentViewModel>()` https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing which is scoped to the parent activity.  However view models should not be a dumping ground for shared mutable state - they should represent the state of single views/widgets, sharing view models leads to unpredictable behavior.

Comment: If you don't want to combine the view models, I would try navigation safe args https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#kotlin.  Its fairly simple, and if you are only needing to pass the email string its pretty easy with safe args.  That link is a quite straightforward guide to getting this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different `ViewModel` instances bound to two different `ViewModelStore`s (represented as fragments). If you need a shared `ViewModel`, then you need to use a single `ViewModelStore`. I believe that changing `ViewModelProvider(this)` to `ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())` for both fragments will do the trick, but you will need to find out for yourself if it's suitable for your design.